# XMLHttpRequest For API requests to Amazon MWS

Tags: javascript, amazon-mws

I would like to create a simple personal client based web app using Javascript which spits out Amazon product information based on ISBNs using the 'GetMatchingProductForId' operation - is this possible using a XMLHttpRequest Object or would I have to use one of the given libraries "PHP, C#, JAVA"?

I have experience in PHP and if I could not do the above I would use the PHP library but this would require it to be run on a server which I would rather not do.